# Is it a security issue when a PDF file is downloaded as an executable installer?

Tags: firefox, pdf, download

I am using Firefox 39.03 and I’m subscribed to a few Google Alerts. I recently received several alerts each containing a link to a URL which is a PDF file whose only 
content is a link to a Russian download site that attempts to download an installer rather than the listed PDF file. I find this very suspicious and a possible source of malware because it seems to me it should just download the pdf file. Here is an example:

```
https://berimaber.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/xml-schema-to-dtd-converter.pdf
```

The above pdf file contains just a link to "read/download" the file. The link location is:

```
https://download.myfilesearch.ru/go.php?q=Xml%20Schema%20To%20Dtd%20Converter
```

But when I click on it it takes me to a Russian site that attempts to download an installer with an EXE extension. I downloaded but have not installed.

Comment: Wouldn't touch it with a barge-pole.

Comment: Given the the whole site https://berimaber.files.wordpress.com/ is just a bunch of (presumably malicious) pdf links I would be suspicious as well.

Comment: Neither PDFs nor EXEs are safe to download from untrusted sources.

Comment: You are correct, it should not be an executable. Delete it right away and don't let curiosity kill the cat (your computer).

Comment: An installer cannot be a PDF file and a PDF file cannot be an installer or an executable. This is a pretty clear scam/virus/trojan. No "suspicious" about it, it's 100% malicious.

Comment: I tried sending feedback to google because I got the links from their Alert system, but  I kept getting a "submission failed" error  and from  a search found several reports their feedback system is error prone. Anyone know another way to contact Google?